# Another tag for a button possible?

Tags: c#, tags

is there any posibility to get a second tag (or something else which i can assign a userdefinied int/string/float)?

The reason is, that i have alreday used the ButtonX.Tag, and it would be much easier to have second tag, or something, than put a second int in an array or something...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its better if you create your own class and attach its object to the button tag.

```
class ButtonProperty
{
   public int ID { get; set; }
   public string MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can use it like:

```
ButtonProperty buttonPropertyObj = new ButtonProperty () { ID = 1, MyProperty ="Some property"};
btn1.Tag = buttonPropertyObj;
```

Comment: Thanks very much... seems also an easy way :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [Tuple](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx) for that

```
ButtonX.Tag = new Tuple<int, string>(12, "");
```